# How to upload a photo in contact list with PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I want to upload a photo in the contact list, I don't see any tutorial about this. I have used FILEURI but doesn't find any result..

```
photos[1].value =  new ContactField('photos',largeImage.src, true);
contact.photos = photos;
```

Help me Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
var name = new ContactName();
name.givenName = "MyContact";
contact.name = name;
var photo=[]
photo[0] = new ContactField('photo', "http://www.ust-co.ru/img/logo-new.png", false)
contact.photos = photo;
contact.save();
```

or you can load it from base64 encoded image, just replace the url with it's code.